# Adding a menu overlay to a UICollectionView using LongPress gesture

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've got a UICollectionView that typically contains 100-200 cells that scrolls both horizontally and vertically.  I am trying to provide a simple UIView popup with 3 icons when the user performs a LongPress gesture to allow them to easily navigate to a couple specific cells within the UICollectionView.

I'd like the start of the LongPress to bring up the popup, then the user would drag their finger to one of the three icons and release to select that icon.

The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to get either the view containing the 3 icons or the icons themselves to respond to the end of the LongPress gesture.

Here's a simplification of the UIViewController:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func longTouch(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if sender.state == .began {
            self.menu!.frame = CGRect(x: sender.location(in: self.view).x - 20,
                                     y: sender.location(in: self.view).y - 75,
                                     width: 100, height: 100)

            self.menu!.isHidden = false            
        }
        else if sender.state == .ended {
            self.menu!.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    // Popup for long touch
    var menu: UIView?

    // MARK: UIViewController

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        self.initMenu()
    }

    // MARK:- UICollectionViewDelegate
    ...

    // MARK:- UICollectionViewDataSource
    ...

    // MARK:- UIScrollViewDelegate
    ...

    private func initMenu() -> Void {
        self.menu = UIView()
        self.menu!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.menu!.frame = CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0,
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 50)

        let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(menuLongPressHandler))
        self.menu!.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))
        self.menu!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        // There would be ImageView icons here as well, which I've left out for simplicity

        self.menu!.isHidden = true
    }

    func menuLongPressHandler() {
        print("Long Press")
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Tap")
    }

}
```

Neither the "Tap" or "Long Press" are printed when the LongPress ends while over the View.  Any suggestions on how to get the view to capture the end of that LongPress gesture?

Comment: I found in the documentation why the view never receives any events related to the LongPress.  From the developer docs: "UIKit permanently assigns each touch to the view that contains it. ... Even when the touch location moves outside the original view, the value in the touch’s view property remains the same."  See: [link]https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/HandlngEventsUsingtheResponderChain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH11-SW1[/link]